# Python3 - Windows: pip gives error when installing requests

Tags: python, pip, installation

I'm trying to install the `requests` module for python3 but pip always gives me that error:

Error: https://hastebin.com/usuhojikax.sql

Command: `python -m pip install requests`

Module Link: https://pypi.org/project/requests/

I'm using Python 3.8.2 on Windows 10 Pro NT

Answer (score 0):

It says that it is a PermissionError

`PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'c:\\program files\\python38\\Lib\\site-packages\\accesstest_deleteme_fishfingers_custard_81entw'`

So I would suggest you run it as administrator